# Login to gtalk with strophie and punjab

Tags: xmpp, strophe, punjab

I have setup punjab on port 5281 and ejabbered xmpp server. I am coding a client using strophe.js and able to successfully login and chat with the users on three different domains that i have created on ejabbered. 
What i want to make a client on which gtalk and facebook users can also log in and chat. But i dont know how to connect with gtalk and fb with strophe.js.where to do put connection configuration?
Do i need to put gtalk connection configuration in punjab or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection properties are in Strophe only. Punjab acts as a proxy and creates a XMPP client session automatically to the domain you have in your Strophe config.

So teh Bosh Uri is always the same, only username, password and XMPP domain is different for GTalk, Facebook and others.

Comment: i have tried establishing connection through strophe with gtalk as  conn.connect(kevin.dishnet@talk.google.com, mypassword, function (status) {
        if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('connected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('disconnected');
        }  Still its not working

Comment: i was not able to put error log in comment section so updated your answer with error log

Comment: @kevin_p Please edit your question to add the error log, don't edit someone else answer.

Comment: your Jid should be something like kevin.dishnet@gmail.com and not kevin.dishnet@talk.google.com